# Different behaviors of memory allocation failure

Tags: c++

I am new to C++. Following the book "Thinking in C++", I tried to execute a snippet to set a new handler for memory allocation failure. On my laptop (ubuntu 22.04LTS), the program never prints the expected error message as defined in `void out_of_memory`. However, when I tried the same program on a server (ubuntu 18.04LTS), it works perfectly. Could anyone help to explain why my program behaves differently on the two systems?

Code:

```cpp
// Changing the new-handler
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <new>
using namespace std;

int count = 0;

void out_of_memory() {
  cerr << "memory exhausted after " << count 
    << " allocations!" << endl;
  exit(1);
}

int main() {
  set_new_handler(out_of_memory);
  while(1) {
    count++;
    new int[1000]; // Exhausts memory
  }
}
```

My laptop's output:

```
Killed
```

Server's output:

```
memory exhausted after 8946078 allocations!
```

Comment: imho it's be better to not use `throw` in the description, as it have special meaning (exception) in c++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different configurations and versions of operating systems and kernels can handle memory allocations failures differently.

In one case the process's memory allocation call fails, and you see the behavior you've observed on your server.

But what can also happen is that [the kernel kills the process that's eating all the memory](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/linux-out-of-memory-killer/). That's the behavior you've observed.

You might be able to force the `set_new_handler` behavior by using the `ulimit` command to artificially limit the amount of memory that a single process can use.